# Facebook User Access Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I retrieve the user access token programatically? I want to refresh the token before it expires through program. How do I achieve this using facebook4j or spring social facebook?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: refreshing tokens is only possible on user interaction. there is no way to do that programmatically, the whole point of short living tokens is that it´s NOT possible to just get a new one without user interaction.

Comment: Thank you.. @luschn

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing tokens is only possible on user interaction. There is no way to do that programmatically, the whole point of short living tokens is that it´s NOT possible to just get a new one without user interaction.